# remove role automatically discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

i want to remove first role if user got second role.
but dont why its not working.
please help.

ex - suppose i got one role on joining. then if i manually give new role to user then first
role that got from joining want to remove by automatically.

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
  ],
});

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
  let MemberRole = member.guild.roles.cache.get('874556919354912768');
  member.roles.add(MemberRole);
});

// here im trying to remove role.
client.on('guildMemberUpdate', (member) => {
  let MemberRole = member.guild.roles.cache.get('874556919354912768');

  if (member.roles.cache.some((role) => role.name === 'bee')) {
    member.roles.remove(MemberRole);
  }
});

client.login('my_token');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are searching for the role on `oldMember`, which is an instance of [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) before the update. The [`guildMemberUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberUpdate) event's callback has two parameters.

```js
client.on("guildMemberUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if (newMember.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === "bee")) {
        newMember.roles.remove("874556919354912768");
    }
});
```

Also make sure that your bot's role is above the one you are trying to remove.

Note that the event won't get fired for `GuildMember`s that the client didn't cache. To fix that, you need to enable the partial `GUILD_MEMBER`.

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_MEMBERS"], partials: ["GUILD_MEMBER"] });
```

<sub>Tested using discord.js `^13.0.1`.</sub>

Comment: Thank You for help https://stackoverflow.com/users/9776840/skulaurun-mrusal